# How to make a GridView item label wrap on long text strings?

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView control with two item template columns, each containing a
label control. One of the label controls wraps on long text strings,
increasing the height of the row. The other one does not wrap. Instead, it
makes the label column extremely wide so that it extends outside the browser
window. How can I make this column wrap the way the other one does?

can i set wrap property from css....

```
user               description

user d             descriptiondfgfdfgdfgdfgfdgdfgdfgfdgfdgf

                     gfggfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfg

user               descriptionfdfdfdfdfdf



how to fix width column and apply wrap to label in template grid view????
```

Comment: Is setting column width an acceptable option for you or do you need fluid columns?

Answer (score 1):

Do your strings contain a character that can be wrapped on, such as a space or a dash?  Without that, the browser will just expand the width of the table to contain the entire string.

If that is the case, you can create your own function to take your long string and add a space every xth character so that it can be wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemStyle-Wrap="true"